# How to start an activity twice?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, stack

I have an acitivty A. From there, you can click in the UI and go to activity B that has, among other things, a ListView. In the activity B I have a menu that takes me to activity C. Inside that activity C, I have another menu that can take me to a **NEW** activity B whose ListView will be populated depending on what I did in activity C.

There is my problem. I can't get the activity B to restart from activity C. The only thing it does is to go back to the PREVIOUS activity B (like the back button have been pushed in activity C).

To sum it up, I want to be able to have the following stack of activities:

A -> B > C -> B

However, I can't get to the second B. Everytime I try to start a new activity B from C, it simply takes me back to the first activity B and the listview is not filled.

Am I missing something?

---

Code from activity C to B

```
 Intent i = new Intent(thisContext, B.class); 
 thisContext.startActivity(i);
```

PS: thisContext here is the context of the activity C, which I assign in the own constructor of the activity C, like this:

```
public C() { 
    this.thisContext = this; 
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code from C that starts activity B?

Comment: u can use StartActivityForResult() in activity B.... make C as subactivity...[nice example](http://thedevelopersinfo.wordpress.com/2009/11/11/using-subactivities-in-android/)

Comment: Chris, I have edited my question with the code. Thank you!

Comment: @android_hungry

Thanks man. I replaced all my startActivity's methods for startActivityForResult's methods and it worked! Thanks a lot!

Comment: so should i post that as answer... u can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u can use `startActivityForResult()` in activity B.... make C as subactivity...

[nice example explained here](http://thedevelopersinfo.wordpress.com/2009/11/11/using-subactivities-in-android/)